# Copy cells from one sheet to another based on criteria in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am wanting to use VBA to copy cells from one sheet to another sheet in the same workbook based on if the criteria of certain cells match in both sheets.

Example:
If Sheet1!A1 = Sheet2!A1 Then Copy Sheet1!B1 To Sheet2!B2

I could do it via a function: `=IF($A1=Sheet1!$A1, VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A1, Sheet1!$A1:$D1, 2),"")`
but am at a loss to make it work in VBA.  I thought about an IF|ELSE Statement but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Is it just for that cell, or will you want to loop through the cells?

Comment: Sorry... I will be looping through cells.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
For Counter = 1 To 10 
    If Sheets(1).Range("A" & Counter).Value = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Counter).Value Then
        Sheets(2).Range("B" & (Counter + 1)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("B" & Counter).Value
    End If
Next Counter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copyToSheet()
For i = 1 To 10
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems to loop through the first set of data on Sheet2 and then stop and not continue to the end of the sheet. What could be done to keep looping through Sheet 2 until the end?

Comment: replace "10" with what your last cell of your data is, or if its variable and there are no empty cells in between the first and last data cells, `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row`

Comment: Even when I do that it just does the first "set" and then stops... it will loop through the values of Sheet1 and replace the first one of each row on Sheet1 that matches on Sheet2 and then stops.

Comment: What do you mean by '"set"'? Are there empty cells between groups of filled cells?

Comment: By "set" I mean that Sheet1 has 9 rows with unique values, Sheet2 has those same values repeated randomly over 1702 rows.  When I run the macro it places values for the first 9 on Sheet2 and then stops... it needs to continue through all 1702 rows.

Comment: "randomly", but there's a number in all Sheet2: A1, A2, ..., A1702?

Comment: Yes there is no blanks from A1:A1702... however the data is not numbers but text.